# Scrape application and K8s cluster level metrics using OpenTelemetry collector

Tags: open-telemetry, open-telemetry-collector

I am researching on how to scrape application level metrics as well as the K8s host cluster metrics and forward it to a gateway collector, all using OpenTelemetry. I am referring to the OTel's Github page - https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver.

There is some confusion on which receiver to use to achieve the above use-case and how forward the metrics/logs from this cluster to another otel collector.

Any suggestions here is much appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

Capturing Kubernetes metrics using the [kubeletstats](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/kubeletstatsreceiver) and [hostmetrics](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/hostmetricsreceiver) receivers, needs to have the Collector deployed in Daemonset mode. Capturing Kubernetes events, and cluster level data is done using the [k8sevents](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/k8seventsreceiver) and [k8scluster](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector-contrib/tree/main/receiver/k8sclusterreceiver) receivers with the Collector in Deployment mode. See the respective GitHub readme for each receiver to learn more on their specific settings.

I recommend you use the presets within the [Collector Helm chart](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-helm-charts/tree/main/charts/opentelemetry-collector) to install all of this. If you can't use Helm in your environment to install, I would still use it with `helm template ...` to generate the manifests so you can understand all the RBAC and service implications to get it all configured correctly.

From a telemetry pipeline perspective, It's a good idea to also enable the k8sattributes processor for metrics/traces/logs on your Daemonset Collectors and have all applications send their telemetry through the local Daemonset collector.